# An 80's or 90's animation seen on VHS; bug disguised as a teacher fighting a girl in class

Tags: story-identification, animation

I'm trying to find an animation I seen years ago, I was young so bear with me. It was 80's or 90's seen it on VHS.

It was based in a School and has a teacher fighting students in class. A girl steps up and she is a match for the teacher. You later find out when an exterminator comes to the school. That the teacher is a giant bug disguised as a human. I think the fighting spreads from the school my memory is vague enough. I always thought it was called Bug or Exterminator but neither of them seem to throw up any results.

A Japanese animation and dubbed into English. It was a movie. Not sure, but I think it was based in a current timeline (80's, 90's). Apart from bugs hiding in human form and being hunted by exterminators, it had no other science fiction tropes. Martial arts was used for the fighting scenes.

One scene I remember vividly was the teacher kicking a student out through the window.

Comment: Did the animation look western? Japanese? Russian? Realistic? Cartoony? Stylized?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Too recent, but [*Cagaster of the Insect Cage*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/38663/Mushikago_no_Cagaster) is a pretty good match...

Answer (score 1):

could be [ultimate teacher](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0250793/)

The teacher is part cockroach, there's the main girl who fights him and another hero with tarantula DNA who comes in to fight the teacher

Comment: As similar as it sounds and feels, it is not Ultimate Teacher, it is not so much a comedy. It is darker and there is a transformation when the teacher is revealed to be a humanoid bug/insect